# Why is my Query on SQL Server with two conditions faster than with single condition in Below Case [may be rephrased]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have below Schema

```
-- schema
CREATE TABLE Countries (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ISO VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    ISO3 VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
    ISONumeric INT NOT NULL,
    CountryName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    Capital VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    ContinentCode VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    CurrencyCode VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
)
```

Below Sample Data

```
-- data
INSERT INTO Countries
    (ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, CountryName, Capital, ContinentCode, CurrencyCode)
VALUES
    ('AU', 'AUS', 36, 'Australia', 'Canberra', 'OC', 'AUD'),
    ('DE', 'DEU', 276, 'Germany', 'Berlin', 'EU', 'EUR'),
    ('IN', 'IND', 356, 'India', 'New Delhi', 'AS', 'INR'),
    ('LA', 'LAO', 418, 'Laos', 'Vientiane', 'AS', 'LAK'),
    ('US', 'USA', 840, 'United States', 'Washington', 'NA', 'USD'),
    ('ZW', 'ZWE', 716, 'Zimbabwe', 'Harare', 'AF', 'ZWL')
```

In SQL fiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28d1e/12

```
--Query 1    
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, CountryName FROM Countries
    EXCEPT
  SELECT ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, CountryName FROM Countries WHERE ISO = 'AU'
) AS Z
WHERE ISO = 'IN'
```

Above Query 1 is taking 3 Seconds.
You can see execution plan at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28d1e/11/0

```
--Query 2
SELECT ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, CountryName FROM Countries
  EXCEPT
SELECT ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, CountryName FROM Countries WHERE ISO = 'AU'
```

Above Query 2 is taking 5 Seconds.
You can see execution plan at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28d1e/14/0

Also Execution plan of Query 1 is much simpler than Query 2
Help me understand why a query with two conditions is faster?
Why is SQL Query optimizer choosing this plan?

Comment: Can you show us both query plans?

Comment: First of all both the queries are not same

Comment: Updated my question with links where you can see execution plan @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The fastest: SELECT ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, CountryName FROM Countries WHERE ISO != 'AU'

Comment: Yes, Both are not same. But I was curious why the one looking more complex is faster. Whats happening under hood with SQL optimizer @Prdp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I postulate that the SQL Server query optimizer recognizes that a `WHERE` restriction will be applied to the `UNION` subquery in the case of the 3 second query.  Recognizing this, it applies the outer `WHERE` filter during the actual `UNION` subquery, allowing for the query to complete faster than the second case.

**Update:**

Based on the execution plans of the Fiddle, assuming they are accurate, the first query is doing a sort and a single table scan, while the second query is doing a sort and two table scans.  The plan of the first query would be consistent with scanning once and applying both `WHERE` condtions along the way.  The second query seems to be implementing the `EXCEPT` with a loop/anti-join.

I think the first query is being executed as:

```
SELECT ISO, ISO3, ISONumeric, CountryName
FROM Countries
WHERE ISO <> 'AU' AND ISO = 'IN'
```

Comment: Yes - I couldn't get the fiddle one to load, but run locally the second one is a single table scan with a sort, the second one requires a nested loops, one sort, and two scans.  Analyzed together, the statements get scores of 34% cost and 42% cost (with the remaining 24% belonging to the insert)

Answer (score 1):

In the first query, the query optimizer will use only select * from countries where ISO = 'IN' as it finds that the inner query will be over-written (ignored) by outer where clause

Answer (score 0):

EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that are not output by the right input query.

therefore

The query
--Query 1

you have two steps:
1. EXCEPT, without filters.
2. ISO filter is performed only once after all EXCEPT executed.

The query
--Query 2

Compare with each row of the left input, you should use ISO filter